# How do I do Catmull-Clark subdivision without losing mesh volume?

Tags: mesh, geometry, subdivision-surface, shape-keys, zbrush

ZBrush has a pretty well known way to subdivide without losing volume or details but still using Catmull-Clark and getting the smoothing benefits: https://www.linkedin.com/learning/zbrush-tips-tricks/subdividing-a-model-without-losing-volume

The ZBrush method produces really nice results... Unfortunately I only have access to ZBrush at work and I use Blender for personal projects. Does anyone know a similar method in Blender? I feel like it must be doable somehow with Shapekeys (which are basically Morph Targets) but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Hi :). You can try the Shrinkwrap or Cast modifiers to do the same thing :)

Comment: It would be very nice if the writer of your reference could express themselves in clear, concise language, without constant digression. Do you think you could do it for them?